# Linking Boost 1.61 with mlpack on windows using cmake

Tags: windows, boost, cmake, mlpack

So I've been following [this blog](http://keon.io/mlpack/mlpack-on-windows/) to compile mlpack on windows. I've completed almost all the step except for the final compilation.
I installed cmake 3.7.1 for windows. I get the following error on running the cmake command

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DBLAS_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/projects/mlpack-master/packages/OpenBLAS.0.2.14.1/lib/native/lib/x64/libopenblas.dll.a" -DLAPACK_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/projects/mlpack-master/packages/OpenBLAS.0.2.14.1/lib/native/lib/x64/libopenblas.dll.a" -DARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR="C:/projects/armadillo-7.600.2/include" -DARMADILLO_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/projects/armadillo-7.600.2/build/Debug/armadillo.lib" -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR:PATH="C:/projects/mlpack-master/packages/boost.1.61.0.0/lib/native/include" -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR:PATH="C:/projects/mlpack-master/packages/boost_libs" -DBOOST_ROOT:PATH="C:/projects/mlpack-master/packages/boost.1.61.0.0" -DDEBUG=OFF -DPROFILE=OFF ..
```

On executing this I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1793 (message):
    Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

    Boost version: 1.61.0

    Boost include path:
    C:/projects/mlpack-master/packages/boost.1.61.0.0/lib/native/include

    Could not find the following Boost libraries:

                    boost_unit_test_framework
                    boost_serialization

    Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
    need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
    BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
    to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:270 (find_package)
```

Previously I used Boost 1.63.0 and got the same error. For some reason cmake is not able to detect `boost_unit_test_framework` and `boost_serialization` but it is able to detect `boost_program_options` properly. I'm trying to fix this issue since 2 days. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Tried with `Boost 1.60.0` as well and got the same error!

Comment: Are you sure the serialization library is built? How do you build boost? Can you share the line?

Comment: I solved the issue. Turns out the the `CmakeCache.txt` had my previous setting which was creating the bug. Now the question seems very stupid. Sorry I'm a newbie to `cmake`.

Comment: I'm glad you solved ;)